# User defined contrast coding with 2 categorical and 1 continuous predictor

Tags: matrix, contrasts, lme4-nlme

I would really appreciate if someone could confirm that the contrast matrix that I defined with the `glht` package for my model is correct and that the continous predictor `Time` is correctly included in the comparison. I followed the examples from the UCLA University (http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/testing_contrasts.htm).

**Background:**

In my experiment, I am looking at the effects of `Culture`, `Treatment` (Temperature) and `Time` have on my response variable Y, accounting for the nested variation between Tanks and the variation caused by measuring the same individuals through time (repeated measures). The factor `Culture` has two levels (WT and 31mix) and `Treatment` has three levels (27C, 31C and 32.5C). I measured the variable Y over 30 days. I’m only interested in the following comparisons

- `WT at 27C`     vs    `31mix at 27C`
- `WT at 31C`     vs    `31mix at 31C`
- `WT at 32.5C`   vs    `31mix at 32.5C`

My model and the output table:

```
model_lme<-lme(Y~Treatment*Culture*Time, random=~1|Tank/Subject,correlation=corCompSymm(form=~Time|Tank/Subject), data=DATA)
```

[image]

**Contrast matrix**

I defined the contrast matrix according to the link from UCLA. They specify: “To define the contrast, we can look at the order in which the coefficients are presented in the output, then create a vector the length of the coefficient list (including the intercept).” The intercept is WT at 31C. My contrast matrix for the following comparisons looks like this:

As I mentioned before, the only comparisons that I’m interested in are:

`WT at 27C`     vs    `31mix at 27C`

`WT at 31C`     vs    `31mix at 31C`

`WT at 32.5C`  vs    `31mix at 32.5C`

**My contrast matrix**

```
K <- matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-1), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)

K
```

[image]

```
t <- glht(model_lme, linfct = K)
summary(t)

Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses


Linear Hypotheses:
         Estimate      Std. Error  z value    Pr(>|z|)    
1 == 0   0.0021295      0.0003212   6.629     1e-10 ***
2 == 0  -0.8218989      0.0138738  -59.241    <1e-10 ***
3 == 0   0.0113841      0.0008141   13.983    <1e-10 ***
```

Any help would be appreciated!